# Permanently change the state of abbreviated display of a piece of code?

Tags: emacs

In *scratch* buffer in Emacs Lisp after you evaluated an expression that evaluates to a complex Lisp form, that form is "abbreviated", i.e. some long lists or its inner parts are replaced by ellipses. Looks something like:

```
(let* ((--3 (make-hash-table)) d c (--5 (let ... ... ...)) (--6 0) (--0 (make-
hash-table)) b a (--1 0) --7) (catch (quote --2) (maphash (lambda ... ... ... 
... ... ... ...) --0)) (nreverse --7))
```

vs expanded version:

```
(let* ((--3 (make-hash-table)) d c (--5 (let (--4) (maphash (lambda (k v) 
(setq --4(cons k --4))) --3) (nreverse --4))) (--6 0) (--0 (make-hash-table)) 
b a (--1 0) --7) (catch (quote --2) (maphash (lambda (k v) (when (or (> --6 
150) (> --1 100)) (throw (quote --2) nil)) (setq a k b v) (setq c (car --5) d 
(gethash (car --5) --3) --5 (cdr --5)) (incf --6) (setq --7 (cons (list (cons 
a b) (cons c d)) --7)) (message "a: %s, b: %s, c: %s, d: %s" a b c d)) --0)) 
(nreverse --7))
```

If I press <kbd>RET</kbd> in the expanded or collapsed state, it toggles the state back. Obviously, my first reaction is to try to format the output, so I press <kbd>RET</kbd>! And then it will either collapse or expand, depends on whichever state it was in. If I copy and paste the whole thing, then it is treated as normal text, but is there a faster way of doing it? I.e. I would like to permanently expand it, w/o having to copy-paste.

I couldn't find the function which toggles the state (perhaps I'm calling it incorrectly). It took me a while to realize it was possible to toggle it anyway (yeah, it displays that in a tooltip, but who uses mouse in Emacs?).

Also, I, in general, like the idea, is it possible to apply it to other languages too? Where can I read more about this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two variables control the print out of results of `eval-expression`. in the `*scratch*` buffer:

```
eval-expression-print-length
eval-expression-print-level
```

You could set those to `nil` and the result would always be expanded.

If you just want the <kbd>RET</kbd> to switch to the fully expanded (and not to toggle), you can use this advice to strip the text properties which enable the toggling of display state:

```
(defadvice last-sexp-toggle-display (after last-sexp-toggle-display-only-long-form activate)
  "After the function is called, check to see if the long form had been displayed, and if so, remove property enabling toggling"
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (let ((value (get-text-property (point) 'printed-value)))
      (when value
        (let ((beg (or (previous-single-property-change (min (point-max) (1+ (point)))
                                                        'printed-value)
                       (point)))
              (end (or (next-single-char-property-change (point) 'printed-value) (point)))
              (standard-output (current-buffer))
              (point (point)))
          (if (< (length (nth 1 value)) (length (nth 2 value)))
              (remove-text-properties beg end '(printed-value))))))))
```